# How do I write a template function that handles a struct as well as CPP type like float?

Tags: c++, class, templates

I have structure template with two objects and a template class. I want to be able to have this struct as one of the types that the class object can be and I want the class's functions to be able to manipulate them. At the same types, I want this class to manipulate standard CPP types like int and float.

```
template<typename T>
struct user_type
{
    T obj1;
    T obj2;
};

template<class T>
class array
{
    int length;
    T* ar_ptr;
    
    public:

    void setArray();
};

template<class T> void array<T>::setArray()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
    {
        (*(ar_ptr+ i)).obj1 = 0;
        (*(ar_ptr+ i)).obj2 = 0;
    }
}

template <typename T>
void array<T>::setArray()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
    {
        *(ar_ptr+ i) = 0;
    }
}
```

I tried to give it two different declarations to the set function but I am getting the following error:

```
error: redefinition of 'setArray'

error: member reference base type 'float' is not a structure or union
```

What is the right way to declare this function and instantiate it? I want the same class to manipulate a struct and a start CPP type.

Comment: How many *definitions* (implementations) of the `setArray` functions do you have? What's the difference between the two you have? Why do you have two?

Comment: I need atleast two. One to set the values of the struct and the other to set the values of standard CPP types. I have mentioned both above

Comment: You can't have a single function do different things. For that you need two different functions. Like *specialization* showed in [the answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76139955/440558).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude error: use of class template 'user_type' requires template arguments. Getting this error. Since the struct is also a template when I tried your suggestion

Comment: Side note, consider changing : `T* arr_ptr` to `std::unique_ptr<T> arr_ptr;` which is the recommended way for current C++ (avoid naked new/delete). You can initialize any type T to its default value using {} or T{}. So you could do `*(ar_ptr) = T{};`

Comment: @PepijnKramer Since this is an array, `std::unique_ptr<T[]>` should be used, not `std::unique_ptr<T>`. However the description of the question doesn't state whether `array` is supposed to be a class owning the array or simply a view of an array. In the latter case the use of a raw pointer is perfectly acceptible.

Comment: @fabian You are right ;)

Comment: ot: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have a conflict in your design, or you misunderstand your assignment/exercise or design.... The type `array<T>` can't hold `user_type<T>` objects. Perhaps you're misunderstand the template type `T` which can be different for both (and every other) templates?

I ***guess*** what you really need and want is something like this:

```
template<typename T>
struct user_type
{
    T obj1;
    T obj2;
};

template<typename T>
class array
{
public:
    // Other public members...

    void setArray()
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < length; ++i)
        {
            ar_ptr[i] = {};
        }
    }

private:
    T* ar_ptr;
    size_t length;
};
```

Then for "normal" types you create you array instance like "normal":

```
array<int> int_array;
```

For your `user_type` template you use an instantiated `user_class` template as the type (this example uses `user_type<int>` to make both members of the structure `int` variables):

```
array<user_type<int>> user_type_int_array;
```

In both cases you can call `setArray` and the "right" thing should happen:

```
int_array.setArray();  // Default initialize (to zero) all elements of the array

user_type_int_array.setArray();  // Default initialize all user_type<int> elements
                                 // the obj1 and obj2 should be default initialized
                                 // which for user_type<int> means the will become zero
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This will work for default value initialization. Can you also point to wear I need to modify if I want to initialize it to random values? Something like array[i] = 10 for some standard type and array[i] = {10, 20} for the user_types

Comment: @Mr.Noob Usually you'd create an overload or a new member function and use copy assignment. You could even implement both in one go using a default parameter: `void setArray(T const& value = T{}) { std::fill(ar_ptr, ar_ptr + length, value); }`

Comment: @Mr.Noob You might want to take a look like how [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) works. Or at least use its interface as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I write a template function that handles a struct as well as CPP type like `float`?

##### Method 1: C++17

One way is to use `constexpr if` and `std::is_arithmetic_v` as shown below:

```
template<class T> void array<T>::setArray()
{
    if constexpr(std::is_arithmetic_v<T>)
    {
           //code for int, char, double etc
    }
    else
    {
        //code for other types 
        for(int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
        {
            (*(ar_ptr+ i)).obj1 = 0;
            (*(ar_ptr+ i)).obj2 = 0;
        }
    }
    
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/TqMav97d8)

---

##### Method 2: C++20

This uses `requires` clause.

```
template<class T>
class array
{
    int length;
    T* ar_ptr;
    
    public:

    void setArray() requires(std::is_arithmetic_v<T>);
    void setArray() requires(!std::is_arithmetic_v<T>);
};
//code for arithmetic types
template<class T> void array<T>::setArray() requires(std::is_arithmetic_v<T>)
{
    
    
}


template<class T> void array<T>::setArray() requires(!std::is_arithmetic_v<T>)
{
    
    
}
```

[working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Tqzq18T8E)

Comment: This won't help my case. I need the second function to work for double, int, char as well. I don't want to have 3 more different specializations for it.

Comment: error: use of class template 'user_type' requires template arguments. Getting this error. Since the struct is also a template

Comment: @Mr.Noob See my modified program/answer that use `is_arithmetic` to check for `int`, `char`, `double` etc and `if constexpr` as you want. See [working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/TqMav97d8)

Comment: @Mr.Noob There are 2 ways to do this. Both are shown in my updated answer. Check out the updated answer.

Comment: This works, but is hard to extend. -1. Sometimes going with the good ol' stuff is a better alternative than using the new stuff. E.g. in this case a traits class or e.g. a function `setToDefault` taking a reference to the element that could be overloaded would make it much easier to extend this....

Comment: If an answer shows an approach that I'd consider bad practice, I'd consider it "Not useful". Without mentioning the drawbacks that's not the only problem: An inexperienced programmer could use this kind of code without a second thought decreasing code quality without even being aware of it...